# Firebase Realtime Database Pagination, Showing 20 Records at a Time

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, pagination

I have 62 records with the Firebase Realtime Database.  I want to show 20 records at a time with the table view (`UITableView`).  I can show the first 20 records with no problem.  But the table won't show the next set when the user scrolls down to the bottom.

```
import UIKit
import Firebase

class ReadViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
    var refInventory: DatabaseReference!
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        refInventory = Database.database().reference().child("inventory")
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)

        readData()
    }

    var dataObject = [DataObject]() // DataObject is an `NSObject` object with three properties (id, uuid, number).
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return dataObject.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! MyTableViewCell
        let object = dataObject[indexPath.row]
        cell.uuidField.text = object.uuid
        cell.numberField.text = String(object.number)
        return cell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if indexPath.row >= dataObject.count - 1 {
            readMoreData()
        }
    }

    func readData() {
        let query = refInventory.queryLimited(toFirst: 20)
        query.observe(DataEventType.value) { (snapshot) in
            guard let first = snapshot.children.allObjects.first as? DataSnapshot else {
                return
            }
            guard let last = snapshot.children.allObjects.last as? DataSnapshot else {
                return
            }
            print(first.key);print(last.key)
            if snapshot.childrenCount > 0 {
                for items in snapshot.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot] {
                    let object = items.value as! [String: AnyObject]
                    let uuid = object["uuid"] as! String
                    let num = object["number"] as! Int
                    let myObject = DataObject()
                    myObject.uuid = uuid
                    myObject.number = num
                    self.dataObject.append(myObject)
                }
                self.queryKey = last.key // -LhZCF41n7Xh8g57YN29
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            }
        }
    }

    var queryKey = String()
    func readMoreData() {
        let query = refInventory.queryLimited(toFirst: 20).queryStarting(atValue: queryKey)
        query.observe(DataEventType.value) { (snapshot) in
            // It stops right here //
            guard let first = snapshot.children.allObjects.first as? DataSnapshot else {
                return
            }
            guard let last = snapshot.children.allObjects.last as? DataSnapshot else {
                return
            }
            print(first.key);print(last.key)
            if snapshot.childrenCount > 0 {
                for items in snapshot.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot] {
                    let object = items.value as! [String: AnyObject]
                    let uuid = object["uuid"] as! String
                    let num = object["number"] as! Int
                    let myObject = DataObject()
                    myObject.uuid = uuid
                    myObject.number = num
                    self.dataObject.append(myObject)
                }
                self.queryKey = last.key
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Showing some of the records with a picture below, the table has 20 records starting with -LhZC4FWPCaOGtq03iho, ending with -LhZCF41n7Xh8g57YN29.  When the user scrolls down, I need to show the next 20 records that start with LhZCF41n7Xh8g57YN2B.

[image]

So what am I doing wrong?  I can change `queryStarting` to `queryEnding` or `queryLimited(toFirst: xxx)` to `queryLimited(toLast: xxx)` here and there in order to get the table to load another 20 records except that the table will end up showing the exact same set of records.  Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have achieved the same using below code. You can use queryOrderedByKey for sorting.

## Code:

```
ref.queryOrderedByKey().queryStarting(atValue: self.queryKey).queryLimited(toLast: 20).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in            
    // Do stuff with this page of elements                                                                                                                              
})
```

Maybe some of the methods are deprecated or unavailable because of the latest release of firebase SDK. I did it in 2017.

Thanks

Comment: Thanks.  If I use your code for readMoreData(), the app will read the exactly the same set of records as readData().

Comment: Please use queryStarting instead if queryEnding(atValue:) because it will return opposite then our requirements.

Comment: Hmm...  That's quite close.  If I set the query as let query = refInventory.queryOrderedByKey().queryStarting(atValue: queryKey).queryLimited(toFirst: 20), readMoreData() will start with the 20th record, not with the 21st record.

Comment: It's happening because we have provided 20th record key as starting points. If you'll provide 21st record key then everything worked as expected.

Comment: I can do that.  But when I scroll down to the bottom again after the app finishes reading all 62 records, it will read the very last record 9 times.

Comment: First of all, you need to find the total number of records available. According to the remaining record, you have to pass the limit value dynamically.

Comment: In my case, I filter-out unique element from the array and stop loading the next records but it is not a proper approach so that's why I suggest you need to go with a total count. At that time I am not able to find any other alternatives.

Comment: Thanks.  That works although I don't quite like what I'm doing.  I wish Firebase Realtime Database will also support the cursor like Cloud Firestore.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195104/discussion-between-imhitesh-surani-and-el-tomato).